# How to subtract one polyline from another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

I have two shapefiles (blue_polyline.shp and red_polyline.shp). How to subtract blue line from red line and keep the different line(keep the red line in the third figure).

---

blue_polyline.shp

[image: blue)polyline.shp]

---

red_polyline.shp

[image]

---

Overlay figure

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting (erasing) polygons from polygon using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133264/subtracting-erasing-polygons-from-polygon-using-arcgis-for-desktop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the license that you have. If you have ArcGIS Advanced license, then you can use [Symmetrical Difference](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/symmetrical-difference.htm). Unfortunately, [Union tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) cannot be used because it works only with polygon geometry not polyline:

> All input feature classes and feature layers must have polygon
>   geometry.

If you don't have advanced license, and you have QGIS, then you can use Difference tool from `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Difference` in QGIS 2.14.15, as follows:

[image]

Input polyline:

[image]

Difference polyline layer:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for in ArcGIS is the `Erase` tool in the data management toolbox. This tool is only available if you have an advanced license however...

If you don't have access to the `Erase` tool, read the following workaround: [Subtracting Polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133264/subtracting-erasing-polygons-from-polygon-using-arcgis-for-desktop) which also works with Polylines - just use a minor buffer on them first, in order to convert them to polygons.