# Performing Row (Element or feature)-wise Union using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have a number of features which I would like to individually Union with itself to remove internal gaps. The best way I've thought of so far is to use cursors and iterate through, essentially performing the Union as many times as I have rows in my feature class.

Is there a tool or other approach that might be more efficient?

Note I do not want to Union everything in the feature class together - the individual results should stay separate and should have as many rows output as I originally input.

I'd like to perform this in one of Esri's products/ArcPy (ArcGIS Pro preferred over ArcMap).

Per @Keagan Allan I tried the dissolve tool but wound up with the same polygon - the interior gap was not removed. A polygon example is below. (Note the view is filtered to only show this polygon - see second image.)

[image: Feature: buffered line output with a gap]

The second image shows that the polygon is overlapping several other polygons which need to be kept separate (and if they have gaps, those gaps should be removed as well.)

[image: many overlapping polygons, one of them with a gap]

UPDATE: The "[Eliminate Polygon Part](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/eliminate-polygon-part.htm)" (Advanced license) tool worked. I don't know whether something similar to this tool is available in other license levels or open source GIS, as replicability is a concern. (It may be better to use the repeated union for that reason.)

```
arcpy.management.EliminatePolygonPart("input_layer", "output_layer_eliminate", "PERCENT", "0 SquareMeters", 99, "CONTAINED_ONLY")
```

UPDATE2: I tried @FelixIP's method in arcpy (Python 2.7) and see a change in the outer border but it's no longer following the line. In the below screenshot, the greenish line is the resulting polygon from the code below, and the cyan is the original polygon.

I did the "check for gaps" and "remove gaps" separately because I wanted to examine the results of the first operation before proceeding, but theoretically could combine the two.

```
# Identify whether a polygon has an interior gap
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("infc", ["uniqueid", "SHAPE@", "HasInnerRing"]) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        print(row[0])
        for part in row[1]:
            partlist = [pnt for pnt in part]
            #print(partlist)
            if None in partlist:
                print("{} has inner ring".format(row[0]))
                row[2] = 1
            else:
                row[2] = 0
        cur.updateRow(row)


# Remove gaps, if they have been identified in previous step
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("infc", ["uniqueid", "SHAPE@", "HasInnerRing"]) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        if row[2] == 1:
            part = row[1].getPart(0)
            pgon = arcpy.Polygon(part)
            row[1] = pgon
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered the dissolve tool? Assigning common field values to rows you want combined and then dissolving?

Comment: Thanks @Keagan Allen. I tried the dissolve tool but wound up with the same polygon - the interior gap was not removed.

Comment: Ok. That gap is no data. You just need to delete the vertices to close the polygon.

Comment: I can type up a proper work flow if you want a more robust technique?

Comment: That would be appreciated; I will need to do this for several thousand locations so I'm looking for a method I can automate easily (not via a manual edit session.)

Comment: What license do you have? I am replying through the app. But I'll post a workflow to try.

Comment: Please try to focus this question on a single GIS product and if you want to also ask about alternatives you are welcome to do that in different questions. That way you can be more detailed (tools and parameter values) about the workflow you have tried and are stuck on. The solution may be similar for ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Desktop 10.x but I would also focus on one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo. Ideally, I want ArcGIS Pro so I can keep in one script.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. First I would add an integer field for HasGap and use an UpdateCursor and Geometry to update with 1 for polygons with gaps. Use Select to pull out polys with no gaps into new FC. On one gapped polygon at a time use Select, Union with no gaps, Append to complete the no gaps FC.

Comment: Ok. I see now why my answer wouldn't help

Comment: @PolyGeo could you expand on your suggestion to use Geometry to indicate polgyons with gaps?

Comment: I think figuring out how to use Geometry to determine whether a polygon has an internal gap (making it a donut polygon) should be the basis of a separate more focused question. It's not one I already know the answer to but I would expect it to be answerable.

Answer (score 4):

This field calculator expression (to run on field Shape) works on single part polygons. Use add geometry attributes (parts count) to find out if this is a case. If not, use multipart to single part tool. In any case first test on backup version of your set.

```
def outRing(shp):
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 pgon=arcpy.Polygon(part)
 return pgon
#-------------
outRing( !Shape!)
```

Keep this in mind when dealing with arcs [getPart() method returns incorrect geometry from buffer in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217395/getpart-method-returns-incorrect-geometry-from-buffer-in-arcgis)

Comment: Great! I'll give this a try and accept / update once tested.

Comment: I received the following series of errors:   `ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
 Unable to update area or length field in response to shape update
 Failed to execute (CalculateField).`  I tried on both the original unprojected dataset (WGS84) and projected (USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area)

Comment: FelixIP's solution works on shapefiles but not GDB layers. Still testing.

Comment: With fgdb start editing first.

Comment: Do I need to swap to Desktop for this stage? For [Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/overview-of-desktop-editing.htm): "ArcGIS Pro automatically starts an edit session when you modify existing data or create new data. Saving or discarding your edits automatically stops the edit session. Any subsequent edits you make resumes the edit session until you save or discard your edits.

There are no buttons to start or stop an edit session"

Comment: Wow, yet another reason of placing pro on hold.

Comment: I tried the suggestion via arcpy (see updates in original question) and the resulting polygon doesn't precisely follow the original polygon shape. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create an envelope around your study area, ensuring the main polygon extent is covered.

Run an erase between the polygon you want to fill and the envelope.

The erased layer should have a mix of big and small polygons. The small polygons are the gaps.

With the erased layer, create a field called area and calculate the area of the polygon.

Decide the area threshold (the maximum area you decide is a gap in the polygon).

Run the select by attributes and select all polygons smaller than the threshold.

With the selected polygons, run a merge with the original polygon.

Select these gap polygons again from the merged polygon you just created.

With these gaps selected run the Aggregate tool.

The gaps should be gone.

NOTE: I think the erase tool is Advanced only. Oh can maybe try ET Geowizards in Arc or try find the erase tool in QGIS.

Comment: I don't think this will work for my situation, but I appreciate the response. (There are thousands of polygons to do this on, so it sounds more efficient to select each polygon one-by-one and Union disallowing gaps.)

Comment: Give it a go. Or maybe post a pic of your dataset.

Comment: Erase is easily implemented using Union and Select when only a Basic license is available.

Comment: @PolyGeo thank you. I will look into t. I always wondered how ET Geo was able to get the same result.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/133268/115

Comment: This is 3-liner in field calculator. Unfortunately question is on hold.

Comment: @FelixIP I'm guessing that there's a removeGaps method you are going to apply to each polygon geometry as the field calculator cursors through. I'll re-open to give you a chance to add your answer.

Comment: This one, please.

Comment: @FelixIP it's open now